# CygWin rSync can't access file folder on Windows 7 with Vagrant

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, rsync, vagrant

**Facts-**

1. Machine is connected to domain
2. User is a domain user
3. Windows 7 running Cygwin with SSH / Rsync set up multiple times
4. Running the rsync command from Cygwin finds the directory "c:\code" just fine but the same command in the windows command prompt gives invalid file or directory error.

**What I have tried -**

1. Changing relative path to static in Vagrant file "code" to "cygwin/c/code" - error thrown "can't find a valid path"
2. Change permissions on the folder (no luck unless I did it wrong)
3. A BUNCH of other stuff from Googling and such

It works fine on my Windows 8.1 machine as well as my Ubuntu (without Cygwin on Ubuntu of course) but for the life of me I can't get over this hump.

Any ideas?  Please feel free to comment to request more information as I didn't want to make the question an essay but I do want to share whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder name is the correct case. In windows code, Code and cODE are all the same.

Try renaming your folder to foo, then back to code, making sure that you only use lowercase characters.

Comment: Sorry wasn't it, appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

As noted Cygwin wasn't recognizing the path because it was a windows path and wasn't prefixed with cygdrive.

I fixed this issue by editing the vagrant helper.rb file and appending 'cygdrive/' in front of the host path.  It's a dirty fix for sure, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue whereby rsync in cygwin is looking for the **/c** path but in my installation the drives are under /cygdrive. A workaround is to create a symlink

`ln -s /cygdrive/c /c`